# click counter increasing Clicks, without any click, Any time edit my post in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, counter

I am using WordPress. I use this click counter : www.phpjunkyard.com/php-click-counter.php

Everything is good but any time save edit post or create post, counter increase 3 number without anybody click it!

Means 3 times edit that post, counter show clicked 9 times! In the event that realy = 0. Tested other plugin and scripts but that has same problem.

Comment: As the website domain suggest, this click counter is junk. You should use a Wordpress plugin instead, like [this one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/baw-post-views-count/).

Comment: @vard I exactly used this plugin before this script that have same problem. this problem not for own plugin or script, WordPress or my template Cause this

Comment: This is definitely a function that should be loaded as a plugin. If the one @vard linked does not work, open a support request with the author or  look at some others. It could also be that there is a legitimate behavior happening that is causing the script to trigger three times.

Comment: I've not looked at the code (code is better in the question anyway) but I wonder if there is some JavaScript that is attaching an event three times when it should only be attached once.